# Forcing a higher generality level of member pointers in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inheritance, pointer-to-member

In Visual C++, Microsoft can represent member function pointers in one of four different formats, depending upon how generic of class inheritance it needs to support.  One of the four, unknown inheritance, is hidden.  The three types exposed to the user are single, multiple and virtual inheritance.

When you declare a pointer to a member function for a class, the size and internal representation of that pointer depends upon how the inheritance model is set up.  Whether a class uses single, multiple or virtual inheritance determines its member pointer representation.  If a class is merely *declared* rather than *defined* when a member function pointer is declared for it, Visual C++ doesn't know what to do and must choose a default size that may be wrong.

To deal with this, Visual C++ supports the extension keywords `__single_inheritance`, `__multiple_inheritance` and `__virtual_inheritance`.  These keywords tell Visual C++ which type of inheritance a class uses so that member pointers may use a proper type.

The problem is that Visual C++ only seems to let me use these keywords to specify the *exact* type of inheritance - it does not let me choose an inheritance worse than the actual one.  This means that I cannot use member pointers in certain completely legal ways.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

struct A {
    int a;
};

struct /*__multiple_inheritance*/ B {
    short b;
    const void *GetThisB() const { return this; }
};

typedef const void *(B::*Vp)() const;

struct C : A, B {
    long long c;
    const void *GetThisC() const { return this; }
};

int main() {
    std::printf("size of Vp: %u\n", static_cast<unsigned>(sizeof(Vp)));

    Vp bvp = &B::GetThisB;
    Vp cvp = static_cast<Vp>(&C::GetThisC);

    C obj;

    std::printf("(B *) &obj=%p, (C*) &obj =%p\n", static_cast<B *>(&obj), &obj);
    std::printf("GetThisB()=%p, GetThisC()=%p\n", (obj.*bvp)(), (obj.*cvp)());

    return 0;
}
```

If you compile this with 2010-2013, Visual C++ reports a warning.  This warning happens because type C uses multiple inheritance, but type B's member function pointer only uses single inheritance, because type B is single inheritance (or rather, no inheritance).

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

multiinherit.cpp
multiinherit.cpp(23) : warning C4407: cast between different pointer to member
representations, compiler may generate incorrect code
```

Sure enough, its code is wrong.  The bottom-right number should equal the top-right:

```
C:\Projects\temp\tests>multiinherit.exe
size of Vp: 8
(B *) &obj=000000000029F914, (C*) &obj =000000000029F910
GetThisB()=000000000029F914, GetThisC()=000000000029F914
```

If I uncomment the `__multiple_inheritance` keyword, which directs Visual C++ to use multiple inheritance mode for member function pointers on type B, I get the following compiler error because type B in fact uses single inheritance.  It doesn't allow the mismatch, even though `__multiple_inheritance` is more pessimistic than `__single_inheritance`.

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

multiinherit.cpp
multiinherit.cpp(7) : error C2292: 'B': best case inheritance representation:
'multiple_inheritance' declared but 'single_inheritance' required
        multiinherit.cpp(7) : see declaration of 'B'
```

If I hex-edit c1xx.dll in the x64 Native Visual Studio 2010 SP1, changing two bytes at offset `0x0C9F61` from `0F 85` to `EB 04`, I bypass this error, and the compiler actually does the correct thing.  This shows that this is an arbitrary limitation of the compiler and nothing fundamental.

```
C:\Projects\temp\tests>multiinherit.exe
size of Vp: 16
(B *) &obj=000000000014FC54, (C*) &obj =000000000014FC50
GetThisB()=000000000014FC54, GetThisC()=000000000014FC50
```

GetThisC is now returning the correct "this" value when called through the member function pointer.  Clang++ and GCC also work fine with this code, so this is limited to Visual C++.

How can I fix this without having to patch the compiler?  I can't use `#pragma pointers_to_members` or the equivalent `/vm*` compiler switches, because I'm writing library code - these are global options and something I cannot force upon the library's users.  `#pragma pointers_to_members` can only be used once; it's basically equivalent to the command line options in that regard.

Comment: Don't take this wrong, but on a high-level, what are you trying to accomplish by using (IMO) hacks like this?  Looks like an XY problem: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I have a base class that has thousands of derived classes via a code generator.  This base class needs to be able to access certain members of the derived classes.  This information is stored in a per-class static table.  I wanted to use a member function pointer.

Comment: Maybe you can use a `std::function` instead?

Comment: @C.R. Hmm.  That would work, since member pointers are small enough that `std::function`'s usual call to `malloc()` wouldn't happen.  It would slow down program startup, though, since `std::function::function()` isn't `constexpr` and the number of calls is high.

Comment: Can you use CRTP instead of function pointers to call the derived method?